# my sorting function sortResult is not working not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i am trying to make a function that sorts the data by id or by name but its not working i need props department name and departmnet id to sort which i have given still its not working.
when is console prop it shows a blank and for asc  it shows true or false

here is the code (i have removed some parts of code which r not related to sorting):

```
const Department = () => {

    let [department, setDepartment] = useState([])
    let [filteredDepartment, setFilteredDepartment] = useState([])
    
    let [values, setValues] = useState({
        modalTitle: '',
        departmentName: '',
        departmentId: 0,

        departmentIdFilter: "",
        departmentNameFilter: "",
        departmentsWithoutFilter: [],
    })


    useEffect (() => {
        getDepartments()
    }, [])

    
    let sortResult = (prop, asc) => {
        console.log(prop)
        console.log(asc)
        const sortedData = filteredDepartment.sort(function(a, b) {
            if(asc){
                return (a[prop]>b[prop]) ? 1 : ((a[prop] < b[prop]) ? - 1 : 0)
            }
            else{
                return (b[prop]>a[prop]) ? 1 : ((b[prop] < a[prop]) ? - 1 : 0)
            }
        })
        setDepartment(sortedData)
    }


    let getDepartments = async () => {
        let response = await fetch (variables.API_URL + "department")
        let data = await response.json()

        setDepartment(data)
        setFilteredDepartment(data)
    }

    return (
        <div>

            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary m-2 float-end" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onClick={() => addClick()}>Add Department</button>

            <table className="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <div className="d-flex flex-row">

                                <input className="form-control m-2" onChange={(e) => {changeDepartmentIdFilter(e)}} placeholder='Filter' />
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-light" onClick={(() =>sortResult(values.departmentId, true))}>
                                    sort a
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-light" onClick={() => sortResult(values.departmentId, false)}>
                                    sort b
                                </button>

                            </div>
                            DepartmentId
                        </th>
                        
                        <th>
                            <div className="d-flex flex-row">

                                <input className="form-control m-2" onChange={(e) => {changeDepartmentNameFilter(e)}} placeholder='Filter' />
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-light" onClick={() => sortResult(values.departmentName, true)}>
                                    sort a
                                </button>

                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-light" onClick={() => sortResult(values.departmentName, false)}>
                                    sort b
                                </button>

                            </div>
                            DepartmentName
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Options
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {department.map((dep) => 

                        <tr key={dep.DepartmentId}>
                            <td>{dep.DepartmentId}</td>
                            <td>{dep.DepartmentName}</td>
                            <td>
                                
                                {/* >>>>>>EDIT BUTTON<<<<<< */}
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-light mr-1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onClick={() => editClick(dep)}>
                                </button>

                                {/* >>>>>>>DELETE BUTTON<<<<<<<<<<< */}
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-light mr-1" onClick={() => deleteClick(dep.DepartmentId)}>
                                </button>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            )}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort` is an in-place sort, meaning it mutates the array it operates over. It also happens to be the `filteredDepartment` state. You mutate `filteredDepartment` and save the current state reference into `sortedData` and then save that back into state. A new array reference is never created.

Copy the `filteredDepartment` array first, ***then*** sort the elements. `Array.prototype.slice` works well here to shallow copy the array into a new reference.

```
const sortResult = (prop, asc) => {
  const sortedData = filteredDepartment.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
    if (asc) {
      return (a[prop] > b[prop]) ? 1 : ((a[prop] < b[prop]) ? - 1 : 0)
    } else {
      return (b[prop] > a[prop]) ? 1 : ((b[prop] < a[prop]) ? - 1 : 0)
    }
  });
  setDepartment(sortedData);
}
```

### Update - fix the sorting properties

Sorting by the `DepartmentId` property:

```
<button
  type="button"
  className="btn btn-light"
  onClick={() => sortResult("DepartmentId", true)}
>
  sort a
</button>
<button
  type="button"
  className="btn btn-light"
  onClick={() => sortResult("DepartmentId", false)}
>
  sort b
</button>
```

Sorting by the `DepartmentName` property:

```
<button
  type="button"
  className="btn btn-light"
  onClick={() => sortResult("DepartmentName", true)}
>
  sort a
</button>
<button
  type="button"
  className="btn btn-light"
  onClick={() => sortResult("DepartmentName", false)}
>
  sort b
</button>
```

Comment: its still not working how will using slice help??

Comment: @naveed It creates a new array that you can call `.sort` on so you don't mutate the existing state. If this isn't working then we may need a more substantial code example or more detail/clarity on what exactly isn't working and the reproduction steps to effect the issue. What does the data look like that you are trying to sort by specific properties? It doesn't look like you pass a correct `prop` value. You seem to be passing part of the `value` state instead of a property name to sort by.

Comment: https://github.com/naveednaseer/delete_later/blob/master/frontend/src/components/Department.js    this is the github link for the code i am trying to make the sort function on line 47 work the sort function is being called on line  184, 189 , 203 and 208

Comment: @naveed So say a user is typing in one of those inputs, they are updating the `values.departmentName` or `values.departmentId` state, and then they click to sort. What sorts of values are you allowing them to pass into your sorting function? Do they know the object property names?

Comment: for sorting there is only a button not an input field and on clicking those button it either sorts by id or by name the input field is for like searching and stuff

Comment: @naveed So `sortResult(values.departmentId, true)` should be something more like `sortResult("departmentId", true)` then?

Comment: sortResult(values.departmentId, true)  here i am trying to give it the id's of departments and  a boolean value for asscending or descending sort if that makes sense (sorry i am not explaining my problem properly i've been studying for few hours now)

Comment: @naveed I think I understand what you are going for, but `a[prop]` is a computed property name accessor. If `prop` had the value of say `"foo"`, and you are doing `a["foo"]` it is the same as saying `a.foo`. I'm not convinced passing in `values.departmentId`, or name, is correct here as these don't seem like variables holding property names, but rather they seem like they'd hold property values. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yeah I understand what u r saying cuz if I try to console log values.departmentId it comes out as blank  do u have any suggestion on how I should do it

Comment: @naveed I think it'd be something like `sortResult("departmentId", true)` but I don't know what properties your `department` array objects have other than what you access in the render, i.e. `DepartmentId` and `DepartmentName`.... so maybe `sortResult("DepartmentId", true)`?

Comment: then i can only sort by id  and only in asscending order

Comment: @naveed Pass in either `"DepartmentId"` or `"DepartmentName"` for the `prop` value, and either `true` or `false` for the `asc` value. `sortResult("DepartmentId"|"DepartmentName", true|false)`. See the last update in my answer.

Comment: Oh fixed it honestly you helped alot man thanks i was trying to mutate the state instead of mutating a copy of state  i am dumb still thanks alot couldnt have done it without your help

Comment: @naveed No worries, glad to help.